# Programs don't show up in jobs if I start them in the background with a shell script

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, script, iterm

I want to launch a three programs (2x streamlit, 1x python) in the background with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /Users/mc/src/crypto/ || exit
streamlit run dashboard.py &
streamlit run dashboard_basis_viewer.py &
/Users/mc/.virtualenvs/crypto/bin/python basis_calculator.py &
```

This script works (i.e. the programs start fine) but there are two problems:

1. None of the processes show up under the `jobs` command
2. If I close the terminal (iTerm), all those processes are still running

If I launch the last 3 lines manually from the command line, I don't get either of those problems.  What's going on here? How can I fix it?

Comment: The script does exactly what you write in the first line, not sure what your question is here. What do you want to accomplish at the end (or, in other words, what exactly needs fixing and how should it look like/behave)?

Comment: @nohillside I think the processes I launch should show up unders `jobs` and the processes should be killed if I quit the terminal.  Those are the behaviours if I launched the processes in the command line as opposed to from a script.

Comment: AFAIK `jobs` doesn't show background processes started from scripts (only those you started interactively in the current shell).

Comment: Instead of entering `./myscript`, try `source ./myscript` or `. ./myscript`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What's going on here?

You have a process running a shell. Based on information given in the posted question, the assumption is made this is a `zsh`, but others may be possible. When the posted script is executed, a new process is created to run the script in a `/bin/sh`. This new process starts three new background jobs associated with the `/bin/sh`. The `/bin/sh` then terminates, leaving the three jobs as orphan processes. So when the `jobs` command is entered, the three jobs do not appear, because three now orphaned processes were never jobs of the original `zsh`. Furthermore, when the `zsh` terminates, no termination type signals are sent to the three jobs because the processes are orphans.

### How can I fix it?

If there is a need for the three jobs to appear when the `jobs` command is entered, then a `.` or `source` command can precede the scripts path and name. The script will be executed in the current `zsh` and therefore the first line in the posted script will be ignored. For example, if the name of the script is `myscript` and is in the current working directory, then either of the following could be entered.

```
. ./myscript
source ./myscript
```

If need there is no need for the three jobs to appear when the `jobs` command is entered, then a line containing the `wait` command could be appended to the posted script. This will prevent the orphans from being created, when the following is used to execute the script in the background.

```
./myscript &
```

Finally, the idea of a script could be abandoned in favor of a function instead. Below is an example.

```
myfunction()
{
    local "cwd=$(pwd)"
    cd /Users/mc/src/crypto/
    local "n=$?"
    if [[ n -eq 0 ]]; then 
        streamlit run dashboard.py &
        streamlit run dashboard_basis_viewer.py &
        /Users/mc/.virtualenvs/crypto/bin/python basis_calculator.py &
        n="$?"
    fi
    cd "$cwd"
    return "$n"
}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. Although, if I may ask a brief question to clarify... I know that both `.` and `source` have the same result... but only most of the time, at least on my system in my experience. If I'm attempting to source a script using the `.` alias from a subshell within another script it fails. Only the `source` command works. I've always assumed this was due to the alias not having been set at a global scope and the subshell not loading my .bash_profile / .bashrc / etc.. but reading your answer, it dawns on me that I've just been _assuming_ that all these years. Am I close?